How to change the order or RecyclerView items in GridLayoutManager?
I have written my own implementation of GridLayoutManager to display specific given number of rows and columns of RecyclerView.
The problem is, that the items are being rendered in a top-to-bottom fashion and I need them to be shown from left to right.
This is what I need:

This is what I got:

As you can see, the numbers are increasing from row to row, and not column by column.
Here is my code for the LayoutManager:
package com.digiteq.digiteqtask.presentation.utils

import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView


internal class CustomLayoutManager(
    context: Context,
    rows: Int,
    private val columns: Int,
    isReversed: Boolean = false
) : GridLayoutManager(context, rows, HORIZONTAL, isReversed) {
    
    /* Setting LayoutParams for the child views of the recycler view.*/
    override fun generateDefaultLayoutParams(): RecyclerView.LayoutParams {
        return spanLayoutSize(super.generateDefaultLayoutParams())
    }

    override fun generateLayoutParams(
        c: Context?,
        attrs: AttributeSet?
    ): RecyclerView.LayoutParams {
        return spanLayoutSize(super.generateLayoutParams(c, attrs))
    }

    override fun generateLayoutParams(lp: ViewGroup.LayoutParams?): RecyclerView.LayoutParams {
        return spanLayoutSize(super.generateLayoutParams(lp))
    }

    /* The function has been made for Horizontal Recycler View.
     *  1. It checks for the orientation to be HORIZONTAL.
     *  2. Its spancount has already been set to 2 in this case throught the constuctor at the initialisation time.
     *    i.e,  layoutManager = new AbsolutefitLayourManager(this,2,GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
     *    the spancount = 2 , specifies the no. of rows for HORIZONTAL orientation
     * 3. The rest of the function divides the horizontal screen width by 2 (spanColumnCount = 2 HERE) hence specyfing the column
          width of each view and hence specifying  2 columns (can be made 3, by dividing by three.)
     */
    private fun spanLayoutSize(layoutParams: RecyclerView.LayoutParams): RecyclerView.LayoutParams {
        if (orientation == HORIZONTAL) {
            layoutParams.width = Math.round((getHorizontalSpace() / columns).toDouble()).toInt()
            // its the margin between the items
            layoutParams.setMargins(2, 2, 2, 2)
        }
        return layoutParams
    }

    override fun checkLayoutParams(lp: RecyclerView.LayoutParams?): Boolean {
        return super.checkLayoutParams(lp)
    }

    private fun getHorizontalSpace(): Int {
        return width - paddingRight - paddingLeft
    }

}

